# Abelian (possibly ramified covers) of elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I'd like to understand the fields of definition of abelian covers of elliptic curves In particular, let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$ (say, a number field).

I'd like to understand the possible abelian Galois covers $X\rightarrow E$ (ie, in terms of the standard 'arithmetic' of $E$) - in particular, the ones which are ramified. If we fix a branch divisor $D\subset E$ (ie, require that the map can only ramify over $D$), then the unramified abelian covers of $E-D$ are classified by the abelianized fundamental group $\pi_1(E-D)^{ab}$, or equivalently the geometric fundamental group $\Pi_D := \pi_1((E-D)_{\overline{K}})^{ab}$ equipped with an action of the absolute galois group $G_K$. If $D_{\overline{K}} = \{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$, then $\Pi_D$ should be isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^{2+r-1}$, and is an extension of the usual Tate module $\prod_\ell T_\ell(E)\cong \pi_1(E_{\overline{K}})$ by $K := \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^{r-1}$ on which $G_K$ acts via the cyclotomic character. Ie, we should have an exact sequence of free pro-abelian $G_K$-groups
$$0\rightarrow K\rightarrow\Pi_D\rightarrow\pi_1(E_{\overline{K}})\rightarrow 0$$

(A) Is the above sequence split exact as $G_K$-groups? (of course it is split as abstract groups) Is it split when $D$ is torsion (ie, $D\subset E[m]$ for some $m$).

(B) Is it possible to describe the minimum field over which all abelian covers of $E_{\overline{K}}$ which have torsion branch points are defined? I think I can prove that this field is $K(E^{tors})$, though I'm not sure if there is an easier proof.

Comment: What do you mean by $D$ torsion? It can't be torsion in the usual sense since it has positive degree. Do you mean it is supported on torsion points? Even for that, you need to choose an origin.

Comment: If $D = x_1+x_2$ and $x_2-x_1$ is torsion, say $(f) = n(x_2-x_1)$, the covers given by $z^r = f$ give a map $\Pi_D \to \pi_1 \times {\hat{\mathbb{Z}}}$ with finite kernel.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I've edited the question, so as to refer only to elliptic curves (ie, an origin has been chosen), so by "$D$ is torsion" I mean that $D\subset E[m]$ for some $m\ge 1$.